# List view in android for blogger

Tags: android, blogger

I am planing to convert blogger into an android app by parsing xml into text. I have done with java code.Now, I I want to display it in as list in a activity .I want list view xml code for this java code. Can you help me out with this ?

you can find the xml source from here : http://vestro-blogger-theme.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        String title[];
        String content[];
        String contentHTML[];
        String thumbimage[];

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // You have to change your blogspot address here
            // for example : http://YOURBLOGADDRESS.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
            new StartParsing().execute("http://vestro-blogger-theme.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
        }

        private class StartParsing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                String getURL = params[0];

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(getURL);
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");

                    title = new String[nodeList.getLength()-1];
                    content = new String[nodeList.getLength()-1];
                    contentHTML = new String[nodeList.getLength()-1];
                    thumbimage = new String[nodeList.getLength()-1];

                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength()-1; i++) {
                        Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                        title[i] = new String();
                        content[i] = new String();
                        contentHTML[i] = new String();
                        thumbimage[i] = new String();

                        //Get blogspot title
                        NodeList titleList = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
                        Element titleElement = (Element)titleList.item(i+1);
                        titleList = titleElement.getChildNodes();
                        title[i] = ((Node)titleList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                        //Get blog spot content as HTML
                        NodeList contentHTMLList = doc.getElementsByTagName("content");
                        Element contentHTMLElement = (Element)contentHTMLList.item(i+1);
                        contentHTMLList = contentHTMLElement.getChildNodes();
                        contentHTML[i] = ((Node)contentHTMLList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                        // Make plain text from HTML
                        content[i] = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(((Node)contentHTMLList.item(0)).getNodeValue()).toString()));

                        // Get Post content thumbnail
                        int start = contentHTML[i].indexOf("src=\"") + 5;
                        int end = contentHTML[i].indexOf("\"",start);

                        thumbimage[i] = contentHTML[i].substring(start,end);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Log","XML parsing exception = "+e);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

                // Check the data using log
                Log.d("Log","Title is");
                for(int i=0; i<title.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("Log",title[i]);
                }
                Log.d("Log","content is");
                for(int i=0; i<content.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("Log",content[i]);
                }
                Log.d("Log","thumbimage is");
                for(int i=0; i<thumbimage.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("Log",thumbimage[i]);
                }
                Log.d("Log","contentHTML is");
                for(int i=0; i<contentHTML.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("Log",contentHTML[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am seriously amazed that you are parsing XML data for converting your blog to an app. Maybe you can achieve it but why do such a processs in the first place?

You can simply parse your blog contents by using [BLOGGER API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/).

> The Blogger API v3 allows client applications to view and update
>   Blogger content. Your client application can use Blogger API v3 to
>   create new blog posts, edit or delete existing posts, and query for
>   posts that match particular criteria.
>
> Create browser-based applications and mobile apps that enable people
>   to create and manage their posts from where ever they are.

You may be great at XML Parsing and it may suit you but why complicate tasks when a simple API Call can fetch you results. I would strongly recommend everyone else to use Blogger API instead of XML Parsing.